# Managing package.json & package-lock.json with Git

Tags: json, git, npm, node-modules, dependency-management

I know you're supposed to add **package-lock.json** to your git repo to ensure team members are using the same versions of dependencies.

Running `npm install` will check for a **package-lock.json** and install the versions indicated there. If a lock file is not present it will install packages from their sources as indicated by **package.json**.

Should **package.json** be added to your git repo as well, then?

If not, a new team member who clones the repo would get the lock file but a **package.json** file cannot be generated from a lock file, correct?

Bonus question:
How should one handle merge conflicts in **package-lock.json**? Since they are machine-generated, I find that this happens often and its not always clear how they should be resolved.

Comment: `package.json` is required - if you ever wish to add a package, it will require the use of `package.json` - not to mention it contains the central place for human-readable analysis of packages used AND project attributes (commands, project locations, etc etc)

Comment: Not to mention, you cannot have a project with only `package.json` - npm wouldn't know what to do upon install for new developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, **package.json** should be included as well.
Besides containing project metadata and being required by `npm`, it provides a **clean and concise view of explicit dependencies**.

Regarding conflicts, the best option might be to use one of them entirely (not trying to merge). Or just re-create it from scratch.
You might be having many conflict in the early phases of a project where all main dependencies are being added.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your bonus question:

There's a way to teach Git to automatically 'merge' `package-lock.json` files, using a merge driver and a `.gitattributes` file.

TL;DR

Run this once on each developer machine:

```
git config --global merge.theirs.name "Keep changes of upstream branch"
git config --global merge.theirs.driver "cp -f '%B' '%A'"
```

Add the following `.gitattributes` file to your repo (and commit it):

```
package-lock.json merge=theirs
```

See [my blog post](https://martin.beryllium.net/2019/08/02/automatically-resolve-npm-package-lock-conflicts-using-git/) for a more detailed explanation.